# How Can I Rewrite This More Efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to believe that there's a better way to write the below code. Thanks in advance.

```
var hProtein = $('#protein-lbl');
var hCarb = $('#carb-lbl');
var hFat = $('#fat-lbl');
var hTotal = $('#totalCalories');

// Normal Calc vars
var nProtein = $('#protein-normal-lbl');
var nCarb = $('#carb-normal-lbl');
var nFat = $('#fat-normal-lbl');
var nTotal = $('#totalCalories-normal');

// Hide calculations until bodyweight is entered
hProtein.hide();
hCarb.hide();
hFat.hide();
hTotal.hide();
nProtein.hide();
nCarb.hide();
nFat.hide();
nTotal.hide();
```

Comment: `class` is exactly made for this purpose: `<div id="protein-lbl" class="hideEle">` for all elements. Then you can do `$(".hideEle").hide()`.

Comment: I was thinking purely javascript and yeah... wasn't being the smartest cookie. I'm now using a css class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps giving the HTML elements a class will work?

```
var $ele = $('.class-name');
$ele.hide();
```

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't think of that... Thanks!

Comment: @BRogers - is there a reason you're setting the initial state with JS rather than with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to have the default condition of the page specified in HTML/CSS, so it displays properly at first and you don't have to run a bunch of javascript just to set up the default condition.

So, if what you're trying to do is establish the default condition upon page load, change the display style of all these elements to `style="display: none;"` right in the HTML so they start out with the right state.

Or better yet, give them all a common class name and create a CSS style rule so they are all initially hidden. Doing this in the markup/CSS will prevent them showing and then hiding as your script runs - they will just start out with the right state.

CSS:

```css
.initialHidden {
     display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="totalCalories-normal" class="initialHidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add common class to element the hide it by this way

```
$('.common-class-name').hide()
```

OR

Put all elements in Single div wrap and hide it by that id

Comment: You might want to add more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this :

```
$([
    '#protein-lbl',
    '#carb-lbl',
    '#fat-lbl',
    '#totalCalories',
    '#protein-normal-lbl',
    '#carb-normal-lbl',
    '#fat-normal-lbl',
    '#totalCalories-normal'
].join()).hide();
```

Comment: Why list them all in an array rather than use just one comma separated string?

Comment: This is just a way to avoid a loooooong string :D I know what you are thinking and I agree, this is useless and not recommended ;)

Answer (score -1):

Why not wrap the labels in a fieldset and hide the fieldset